# How to add a cohort filter to a single event in Mixpanel?

Tags: filter, mixpanel, web-analytics, custom-events

I am creating a funnel diagram with two events. The first event tracks the number of logins and the second tracks the number of page loads of a specific page. I want to add a filter on the second event *only* which filters to users in a particular cohort.

Is there any way a cohort can be added to only one event rather than both events in the visual? If not, is there a way to create a custom event in Mixpanel where I can add two events together (e.g. users did event x AND event y). At the moment, the custom events option only lets me combine events using an OR (e.g. users did event x OR event y) and that's not what I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not possible to add a cohort as a filter on a specific step in a funnel nor create a custom event that requires users to do 2 events. That said I do think there may be a workaround using Mixpanels [any order funnels](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360029190092-Advanced-Funnels-Functionality#conversion-criteria-specific-order-or-any-order). If im understanding correctly you want users to have completed 2 separate events in the funnel but it cannot be a traditional funnel as the two steps may not always happen in the same order?

If thats the case then any order funnels would allow you to capture the group of users who did all 3 steps without specifying in what order they completed the events.